# Firebase: export user accounts’ email and password hashes

Tags: export, firebase

I use email/password authentication for my Firebase.

I’m considering moving to a different backend and I’m wondering if there is any way to export user emails/password hashes so that I can authenticate them outside Firebase?

I would also need to know the hashing algorithm.

Comment: Where are you going to export them?

Comment: @nicael Into a MySQL DB.

Comment: This is currently a manual process, and not exposed via the tooling on the website. Contact support@firebase.com and they can handle this for you.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can use the firebase-cli by writing `firebase auth:export save_file.csv --format=csv` or `firebase auth:export save_file.json --format=json`

More details can be found on the firebase documentation page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#authexport

Comment: I’ve tried `firebase auth:export save_file.json --format=json`, but I didn’t get the hashes:
`{
      "localId": "020f4fb0-0344-4ff7-bc47-b5e42b00b717",
      "email": "someuser@gmail.com",
      "createdAt": "1463657902000",
      "providerUserInfo": []
    }`
Since many of my accounts are created in early 2016, I suspect passwords were not hashed using the scrypt algorithm which is required as per note at the beginning of `auth:export` command’s docs.

Comment: In any case, I accept this answer because I guess it would work with this recent platform.

Comment: Once you export the users & hashed passwords, you can use https://github.com/firebase/scrypt to verify user logins.

Comment: is there any way to export just the users that have an email attached to their account?

Comment: Any idea why when I run this, it works, but in console it keeps repeating the message `Exporting accounts to auth_export.csv
✔  Exported 289 account(s) successfully.
✔  Exported 289 account(s) successfully.
✔  Exported 289 account(s) successfully.
✔  Exported 289 account(s) successfully.`

Comment: And the exported file ends up containing the data repeated several times.

Comment: Same issue here, it seems to endlessly loop/append repeating data unless you cancel the command after the first success message

Comment: Is there any chance that this CLI command will include custom-claims in the future as well?

Comment: This may be a bit of a stupid question, but where is the exported file (save_file.csv or save_file.json) saved to? I get the message that ```Exported 56 account(s) successfully``` but can't locate a save_file.csv on my local PC.

Comment: For me, it's always in the same folder I start the script from.

Comment: When I run firebase auth:export 
I get "An unexpected error has occurred. "

Answer (score 50):

I did not get any option on firebase console UI. So you need to install firebase tool using npm.

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

and then login using

```
firebase login
```

after login you need to run one of command

**CSV** Format

```
firebase auth:export save_file.csv --format=csv --project <project-id>
```

**JSON** Format

```
firebase auth:export save_file.json --format=json --project <project-id>
```

you can get the project-id from home screen of [firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/)

Answer (score 3):

ex corret  firebase auth:export save_file.csv --format=csv --project=my-name-project-fb

Comment: It is usually best to explain how your answer addresses the question.